# Why can't I use GroupBy in this DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I created a dataframe called df11.
This was an alter from the main DataFrame. (It's Pokemon by the way..)

```
df11= df.drop(["Name", "#"], axis=1).head(9)
df11
```

this is what i get:

```
    Type 1  Type 2  HP  Attack  Defense Sp. Atk Sp. Def Speed   Generation  Legendary
0   Grass   Poison  45  49  49  65  65  45  1   False
1   Grass   Poison  60  62  63  80  80  60  1   False
2   Grass   Poison  80  82  83  100 100 80  1   False
3   Grass   Poison  80  100 123 122 120 80  1   False
4   Fire    NaN 39  52  43  60  50  65  1   False
5   Fire    NaN 58  64  58  80  65  80  1   False
6   Fire    Flying  78  84  78  109 85  100 1   False
7   Fire    Dragon  78  130 111 130 85  100 1   False
8   Fire    Flying  78  104 78  159 115 100 1   False
```

Now I tried using df11.groupby("Type 2").mean()...

I get:
TypeError: agg function failed [how->mean,dtype->object]

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Most likely, you need: `df11.groupby("Type 2").mean(numeric_only=True)`

Answer (score 0):

The error you mentioned occurs when trying to perform an aggregation function (like mean) on non-numeric columns.
What column do you want to get the mean value?
If you want to get all the mean value that is numeric, you can try like this

```
df11_numeric_means = df11.select_dtypes(include=[np.number]).groupby(df11['Type 2']).mean()
```